# bulk copy out huge table on sybase adaptive server

Tags: sybase, sybase-ase

anyone has a good approach or even strategy to bulk copy out single table with 500+ millions rows. the table encountered unitialized logical page, and we are looking to atleast salvage good records.

we are running sybase adaptive server version 12.5 on linux platform.

TIA

Comment: Does the table have a primary key? Do you have enough space to copy the table within the database?

Answer (score 1):

We have done very large table migrations successfully with Sqoop. Yes, there will be a bunch of setup that is needed but it is tuneable to run in multiple threads for faster performance.

*From Comments:*

Over the years, I have used many methods to extract data from sybase tables. BCP, IBM Optim (very proprietary), Apache MetaModel and Apache Sqoop. Using Sqoop I found is the most effective for very large tables. The setup for Sqoop would need some basic Hadoop libraries to run. Then you would install the sqoop server and the client software. All of this is not very difficult to do. Sqoop does not offically support Sybase but it does work really well. [Here](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.1/Installation.html) is a good starting point for installing Sqoop on a single node.

Comment: Your answer can be improved and will be helpful if you can provide more details - like how you implemented or what settings to do/change when implementing Sqoop (a link referencing to product will help as well).

Comment: Over the years, I have used many methods to extract data from sybase tables. BCP, IBM Optim (very proprietary), Apache MetaModel and Apache Sqoop. Using Sqoop I found is the most effective for very large tables. The setup for Sqoop would need some basic Hadoop libraries to run. Then you would install the sqoop server and the client software. All of this is not very difficult to do. Sqoop does not offically support Sybase but it does work really well. Here is a good starting point for installing Sqoop on a single node. https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.1/Installation.html